# Typescript and context, Type is not assignable

Tags: reactjs, typescript, tsx

Hello I'm learning typescript and I'm having an error of Type, this is  component catcontext.tsx:

```
import { createContext } from "react";

interface structCat {
    id: number,
    idParent: number,
    description: string    
};

const CatContext = createContext<structCat | null>(null);

export default CatContext;
```

and this globalstate.tsx:

```
import CatContext from './CatContext';
import CatReducers from './CatReducers';
import { useReducer } from 'react';
import Data from '../../../Data/Data.json';

const initialState = {
    cats: Data,
}

function GlobalState(props: any){

    const [ state, dispatch ] = useReducer(CatReducers, initialState);


const AddCat = (cat: any) => {
    dispatch({
        type: ADD_CAT,
        payload: cat
    });
}
    return(
        <CatContext.Provider
            value={{
                cats: state.cats,
                AddCat
            }}

        >
            {props.children}
        </CatContext.Provider>
    )

}

export default GlobalState;
```

this is error:

```
Type '{ cats: any; AddCat: (cat: any) => void; }' is not assignable to type 'structCat'.
  Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'cats' does not exist in type 'structCat'.  TS2322
```

the Data.json struct is like:

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "idParent": null,
        "description": "main"
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "idParent": 1,
        "description": "name 1"
    }
]
```

so, I'm trying to create project using context api and typescript, so the type context should be type struct Data.json, I'm not sure is that way is rigth, but my idea is create a struct type that I can add, edit, delect, search and list data.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

`{ cats: any; AddCat: (cat: any) => void; }` doesn't equal `{ id: number, idParent: number,  description: string }`

additional notes:

- cat should be type - structCat
- cats should be type - array of structCat
- Default context shouldn't be null if it can be avoided or isn't really a valid value for the purpose.
- AddCat should be addCat - it's good practice to only capitalize the first letter of react component names

```
interface ICatContext {
 cats: structCat[];
 addCat: (cat: structCat) => void;
}

createContext<ICatContext>({
 cats: [],
 addCat: (_)=>{}
})
```

Comment: You should also add types to your reducer - https://www.newline.co/@bespoyasov/how-to-use-usereducer-with-typescript--3918a332

Comment: ok thanks for it bro!... another one, If I have another function that return one item, I should add inside interface like: selectCat: (cat: structCat) => void ??? or It should be =>  structCat